# Bing Maps AJAX control version 6.3 landmarks have disappeared from the base layer

Tags: bing-maps

I have a map using version 6.3 of the AJAX library.  I was informed by a customer that sometime recently some of the landmarks that were visible on the base layer of the map have disappeared and indeed they have.  If I switch to the enhanced road style the landmarks are there again.  Does anyone know if there is a reason why these disappeared from version 6.3 and if this is documented anywhere?  I know that the opt-in for the new style ends in May 2011 but would like to keep the old style for now until we are able to upgrade to version 7.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that a "landmark" has disappeared, do you simply mean the *label* for that landmark is not shown on the tile, or that the landmark itself is no longer shown?

Assuming that you mean only the label:

The tile images used in Bing Maps are constantly being updated.
You don't state, but I assume that your "base layer" uses the default road view, which displays not only the underlying road network, but also buildings, parks, and other shows labels for certain "landmarks" - e.g. significant public buildings.

As the road map is updated to reflect new developments, changed road priorities etc. then different landmark labels may be shown in order to ensure the map maintains a balance of detail and also readability. This is unrelated to the upgrade to the new map style, but is a continuous process of map updates.

If you mean that the feature itself has disappeared:

Can you provide an example of any particular feature that has disappeared? Does this happen at every zoom level?

Comment: The landmark itself is no longer shown.  I am using the default road view as the base layer.